# Can you use HD-SDI cables to loop antennas for wireless mics?

Tags: microphone, sound, wireless, cable+

We have Line 6 Mic recievers that you can rack together and loop the antennas from one to the next *(see page 26 of [the manual](http://line6.com/data/6/0a064339457b54fa0539221bf/application/pdf/XD-V75%20User%20Manual%20-%20English%20(%20Rev%20i%20).pdf))*.

You can buy the cable from Line 6 [here](http://store.line6.com/accessories/cables/extension-cable-antenna-lmr195-bnc-pair.html), but you can get BNC-BNC cables [here](http://www.primecables.com/p-357537-cab-16180-all-viper-series-hd-sdi-rg6-bnc-cable-monoprice#sku366143) for a fraction of the price.

Line 6 doesn't give any technical spec for their cables, but the other cables are listed as HD-SDI video cables. In my mind, a BNC connector is a BNC connector, and a copper is copper. Is there any reason why we couldn't, or shouldn't use an HD-SDI cable to loop our antennas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, RF antennas coaxial cables have a 50 Ω (Ohms) characteristic impedance whereas HD-SDI cables have a 75 Ω characteristic impedance.

The user manual of your line6 product actually mentions a 50 Ω antenna impedance (page 30).

You should be fine if using 50 Ω coaxial cable, so not HD-SDI cables.